# How can I create auto incremental id column?

Tags: database, auto-increment, vertica

I created a table in HP's Vertica database. I want to create auto incremental column in Vertica.

In MySQL it is already done , and in Oracle I created it by using sequence and trigger but how can I do it in HP Vertica?

Answer (score 8):

It's actually pretty simple just the syntax is a bit different since in Vertica `AUTO_INCREMENT` needs to be specified as the column type. Here's a quick example

```
user=> create table test (
user(>   id AUTO_INCREMENT,
user(>   foo VARCHAR(255)
user(> );

user=> insert into test (foo) values ('hello');
 OUTPUT
--------
      1
(1 row)

user=> insert into test (foo) values ('world');
 OUTPUT
--------
      1
(1 row)

user=> select * from test;
 id |  foo
----+-------
  1 | hello
  2 | world
(2 rows)
```